# What is a constant in Java

Tags: java, constants

I have been looking all over the web, StackExchange, Wikipedia, YouTube, random sites, everywhere but I haven't got a simple answer, or it's been different from what others have said.

Some resources have said, in Java, Constants are variables whose value cannot be changed.

Other have said Constants are objects whose **name** cannot be changed.

And more have said Constants are variables whose name cannot be changed.

Please could someone tell me in English exactly what a Constant is, which parts can/cannot be changed and maybe an example where constants would be used instead of a normal variable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the concept of a 'constant' is not unique to Java. for instance: your can be considered a constant, since if I ask you now, or I ask you three years from now, it'll still be the same. PI is a mathematical constant. 'whose name cannot be changed' -> this just makes no sense at all.

Comment: @DreddTrekkiter I'm afraid this isn't a very useful question. Constant (without a qualifier, like "compile time" or "enum") isn't a rigorously defined Java term. It is generally considered to be a `static final` field with an immutable or primitive type, but there could be other definitions that are just as valid. At the end of the day it doesn't matter much, what matters is how each of the constructs **work**.

Comment: @NarutoBijuMode I suggest you read up more on final. final does NOT mean you can't change it's value, it means you can't change it's reference, huge difference

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102917/discussion-on-question-by-dreddtrekkiter-what-is-a-constant-in-java).

Answer (score 6):

A constant is value that cannot be changed. For example `5`, `0.5` , `"abcd"` etc.

Lets consider Java :

```
int i = 5; // Here 5 is constant but the reference (i) can change and point to 6. i.e, the value 5 is immutable, but the reference (i) is mutable.
```

Adding the `final` keyword to the above statement :

```
final int i = 5; // Here the keyword final ensures that the reference cannot point to any other value.
```

Thus `i` becomes a compile time constant and its value is passed in the byte-code itself.

Note that a reference could point to a constant value (`immutable` object ) or a `mutable` value.

Technically speaking, *immutable* values aren't same as constants in case of reference types (except String).

Answer (score 3):

A constant is something of which everything is **constant**. Name, value whatever you call it. It **cannot be changed**. Some also call it a **literal**.

eg:

- `9` is an integer constant. You cannot change 9. It's name is 9, you call it *nine*, it value value is 9.
- `"ABC"` is a String constant.
- `9.7` is a floating point constant.
- `true` is a boolean constant.
- `'a'` is a character constant.

Comment: This is close to the definition of [constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), but then `"foo"+"bar"` is also a constant expression, as is `42*Math.PI`